# How would you go about proving the following relation about the |sin(x)| value of consecutive numbers?

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

I've been trying to write a formal proof of the following, but it's been rather annoying. any help is appreciated
Prove that for every 3 consecutive numbers n,n+1,n+2. there exists a x = {n,n+1,n+2} number, such that |sin(x)| >= 1/2

Comment: There is nothing special about $n$ being an integer.  Prove it for $n \in [0,2\pi)$ by considering the intervals where $|\sin(x)| \ge \frac 12$.  Then argue you can add or subtract $2 \pi$ to $n$ enough times to get it in this range

Comment: Did someone assign this problem for homework this weekend? This was last asked just seven hours ago.

Comment: Essentially the argument uses that $\frac56 \pi - \frac16 \pi > 1$ and  $\frac76 \pi - \frac56 \pi < 2$

Comment: $\frac \pi 6 < 1 < \frac \pi 3$.  And $\sin \frac \pi 6 = \frac 12$.  Do it in cases.  If $|\sin x| <\frac 12$ then  $m\pi-\frac \pi 6 < x < m\pi+\frac \pi 6$ for some integer $m$.  If $m$ is even and $m=2k$ and If $2k\pi\le x < 2k\pi + \frac \pi 6$ then $2k\pi +\frac \pi 6 \le x+1 < 2k\pi + \frac \pi 2$ and $\sin (x+1) \ge \frac 12$.  And you can do the other three cases similarly.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone!